# Cypher, how do I use MATCH on a result without messing up the original result

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I'm gonna try to make as much sense as possible, It's also very likely that what I've written is not a good approach to what I want to do, in which case I'd appreciate some pointers in the right direction.

What I want to do is create a node:Hang and create relations to each of the nodes:User that are in a defined array, after that, MATCH one of the created relations based on the fb_id on one of its nodes. SET a property on that relationship and RETURN the first nodes:User i matched.

What I have below does all that I want, with the exception of that it returns the user with the matched relation and not my originally matched users.

How do I make it so it returns the original matched users? (xxxx, zzzz)

```
 CREATE (hang:Hang {})
 WITH hang
 MATCH (users:User) WHERE users.fb_id IN [xxxx, zzzz]
 CREATE (users)-[:member {status: 0}]->(hang)
 WITH users, hang
 MATCH (users)-[r:member]->(hang) WHERE users.fb_id = xxxx
 SET r.founder = 1, r.status = 1
 RETURN users
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you make sense. I made an example. Here are three users:

```
CREATE (:User {fb_id:1234}),
       (:User {fb_id:5678}),
       (:User {fb_id:9101});
```

Then, if you want to create a `[member]` relationship from Users 1234 and 5678 to Hang, but only set `founder=1` and `status=1` for User 1234 while still returning both users:

```
CREATE (hang:Hang {name:'Some Hang'})
WITH hang
MATCH (users:User) WHERE users.fb_id IN [1234, 5678]
CREATE (users)-[r:member]->(hang)
SET r.founder = CASE WHEN users.fb_id = 1234 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END,
    r.status = CASE WHEN users.fb_id = 1234 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END
RETURN users;
```

This returns both Users 1234 and 5678 in the end, but only sets `founder=1` and `status=1` on the `[member]` relationship between User 1234 and Hang.

Comment: Nice! I was thinking about a conditional SET, but wasn't quite sure how to make it as neat as you did. That's exactly the approach i was looking for. Thank you so much